# Time Complexity Analysis for Word Break

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

What is the time complexity analysis and the space complexity analysis for the following code:

```
class Solution:
    def wordBreak(self, s: str, wordDict: List[str]) -> bool:
        if not s or not dict:
            False

        N=len(s)
        ans=[False for i in range (N+1)]
        ans[0]=True


        for index in range(N):
            if ans[index]:
                for word in wordDict:
                    L=len(word)
                    if index+L <= N and s[index:index+L]==word:
                        ans[index+L]=True

        return ans[-1]
```

Given a non-empty string `s` and a dictionary `wordDict` containing a list of non-empty words, determine if `s` can be segmented into a space-separated sequence of one or more dictionary words.

Comment: `O(N * |wordDict|)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time complexity of this solution is `O(n*m*k)` - where:

- `n` is the length of the string `s`.
- `m` is the number of words in `wordDict`.
- `k` is the average length of a word in `wordDict`.

Explanation, you repeat `n` times, for each you check each word in `wordDict` (`m` total), and for each such repeat, you read the entire word (of length `k`).

Space complexity is `O(n)` - your aux array is independent on the number of words in `wordDict` or their length, and there is no extra space allocation <sup>1</sup> depending on the dictionary.

---

(1) Well, I am not sure how python implements the `s[index:index+L]`, but either way, this is not multipled by `n`, and never allocated more than once at a time, and never allocared if `L > n` - so it does not affect space complexity either way.